# ArrayFire af::eval() premature data type mismatch error

Tags: arrayfire

This code is giving me datatype mismatch error.

```
const double dd = 0.225;
af::array aa = af::constant(111, 10, f32) + dd;
af::array bb = af::constant(111, 10, f64) + dd;
af::eval(aa, bb);
```

Both aa and bb should be f64 because both add a double value. There shouldn't be a datatype mismatch error.

I got their response on [github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/2426](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/2426), it remains as f32 after adding the double scalar on purpose. Anyway, it is actually a good thing for me to write program that supports precisions based on the caller's input. So, it is actually a good feature I want to keep. Marking this as resolved.

Comment: That shouldn't have happened, which version of ArrayFire are you using ? Which backend ?

Comment: I have checked the code and it seems the developer who wrote the relevant code was intentionally falling back to single precision in the case where the second operand is a scalar even if it is double precision.

If you think there are pitfalls with this behavior, please raise the issue on github.
https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues

We can discuss with it our team on github issue and take it forward from there.

Comment: That must be it. I will raise the issue on GitHub, thanks.

Comment: I wrote an issue on their GitHub https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/2426

Comment: I got their response, it remains as f32 after adding the double scalar on purpose. You can read their justification on the link on my previous comment. Anyway, it is actually a good thing for me to write program that supports precisions based on the caller's input. So, it is actually a good feature I want to keep. Marking this as resolved.